# How to find out which markers are currently within displayed map limits

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check if map markers are within selected bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229711/check-if-map-markers-are-within-selected-bounds)

I have couple hundreds markers, but for convenience, I would like to 'grey-out' some options for markers which are not currently visible on the map (they are on the map, but outside the currently viewed map boundaries.)

As a solution, I think that I  need to loop over all my markers (I have an array, so this is not a problem), but I don't know how to check if marker is currently within visible boundaries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100514/google-maps-v3-check-if-marker-is-present-on-map

second answer should be what you are looking for ;)

Comment: @chsymann, Thank you add as official answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())
```

It will return true if the marker is inside your map boundary, false otherwise.