# Google places api returns duplicate places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm searching for places by keyword within an array of LatLngBounds.

```
    var boundsarr = new Array();

    boundsarr[0] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.941886953491675, -80.17411103748543),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.947676224813897, -80.16767330177947)
    );
    boundsarr[1] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.941886953491675, -80.16767330177947),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.94622890698334, -80.1644544339265)
    );
    boundsarr[2] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.1644544339265),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.94622890698334, -80.15962613214703)
    );
    boundsarr[3] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.15962613214703),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.931755728677782, -80.15801669822054)
    );
    boundsarr[4] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.15801669822054),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.933203046508336, -80.15318839644107)
    );
    boundsarr[5] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.92886109301667, -80.15318839644107),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.933203046508336, -80.15157896251458)
    );
```

then adding markers on the map, to and array, and creating a list of places returned using the markers array. Duplicate entries show up in the list and I can't figure out why..

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2KrmY/. How can I prevent duplicates from showing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, just realized now, you're calling nearbySearch inside a loop with a LatLngBounds for each call, I did not get a chance to check it but I think that might be the issue..maybe your bounds are getting overlapped or might be a precision thing?

Comment: No problem. Yes I'm doing a nearbySearch for each bound. I'm sure it's related to the loop but I've been looking at the code and can't figure where it's overlapping...

Comment: It's not overlapping somewhere, the duplicates are a result of the search for boundsarr[1]. When you create a rectangle of the bounds you will see that returned places(Cafe Que Rico and Net Place Cafe Inc) are not located within the defined bounds. By this, you may call this a bug, I would call it a inaccurate result.

Comment: @Dr.Molle thanks! Do you think this is an API bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an interim solution, could you build an array of found places in your Callback each time and then within the same loop, see if the place has a count of >1, then don't call createMarker if so?

Not sure if perfect, but see below:

```
var foundPlaces = [];
var found;

function callback(results, status) { 
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      found = 0;
      foundPlaces.push(results[i].id);
      for (var j = 0; j < foundPlaces.length; j++) {
        if (foundPlaces[j] === results[i].id) {
          found++;
          console.log(foundPlaces[j], results[i].id);
        }
      }

      if (found < 2) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2KrmY/15/

Comment: Thanks this might be the only solution if there is no way to avoid duplicates from the request itself.

Comment: an easier way is to compare the markers array of existing markers and new markers using `markersArray[i].getPosition().equals(marker.getPosition())`

Comment: it would be better to use a hash map. this can be n^2 or greater at worst possible. foundPlaces could be a dictionary a hash rather then a dictionary

Comment: @TravisDelly Yep, which are supported now in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 3):

The bounds parameter is described as below:

> The bounds **within** which to search for Places. Both location and radius
>   will be ignored if bounds is set.

But for the second bounds in your code example, 2 results outside the bounds get into the result.

You could display the bounds area by using:

```
new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: 'bulue',
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds
});
```

And then you can see the result.

***[Check The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2KrmY/16/)***.

This may be a bug of the google map api.

Comment: Yes that is very weird behavior. I get duplicates when searching anything in multiple bounds in a loop.

Comment: @CyberJunkie Yes, the results is in your third bounds again.

Comment: do you know if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check before adding new bounds, as when you click again it generates new marker in the same place..
use this...
`map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())`

refer [old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100514/google-maps-v3-check-if-marker-is-present-on-map)

this will return `true` or `false` after checking this you may render/add the marker

I have tried in the fiddle but still no success... as its JASON syntax..
and JavaScript require specific function for the user defined data type.. I am trying to create custom function to eliminate duplicate JSON object....

I will keep you posted with updated fiddle as soon as its ready, till then you may try on your own..

I hope this will do..

Comment: Thank you, it's true that markers are created in the same bounds on each request but the issue is that duplicate markers are created outside their bounds (in another bounds).

Comment: You can check if a marker is already on the map by simply storing each marker in an array and check if it exists every time you create a new marker. Matt posted an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17139868/468312

Comment: Yes I have tried that but as the marker is created using JSON Notation its not getting compared before pushing it in the array.... I was working on that but Matt solved your problem so that did it :) although we can make it better by comparing.. here Matt checks it marker in array are more then 2 it will not check again.. so that works on count basis.. :)

Comment: You can check before pushing to the array by removing the map object `map: map` from the json notation, then do your compare/push to array and finally place the marker on the map using `marker.setMap(map);`